# How to download file in computer silently using PHP?

Tags: php, html, browser, download, force-download

I want to download the files silently or without prompt to the computer using PHP? OR when click on the download link, can I force to download in defining location? Like `C: /dir/dir/myfile.zip`? Note that I am asking this for my internal use only, nothing to harm the users.

Comment: `<sarcasm>`Gee, I'd sure LOVE it if this was possible, so that spammers and malware pushers could fill up my machine without me having to click through all those tedious UAC prompts. What a brilliant Idea!`</sarcasm>`.

Comment: Remind me never, ever to visit your web pages - if you want to download malware to my machine... and there is no justifiable personal need to ever do so

Comment: There is no legitimate reason to do this. You should be looking at cookies and sessions and/or HTML5 Local Storage probably.

Comment: He may have some custom application on a local network that needs to do something like this.  He specifically mentions that this is for some personal or internal purpose in his question.

Comment: That may be, but why not just use rsync or scp or another service that works over ssh? I can't imagine any possible legitimate use for this that can't be done much better and quicker using another method. (Plus, he says "when visitors browse my web pages", which clearly indicates this isn't some internal project)

Comment: That's not on the web, but okay, I know what you mean. Anyway, it's not possible to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

It simply isn't possible, due to security issues.

Now, if these are systems on your own private network, and drives are shared and what not, you could write code to write out the files from the server.  But, that is all outside of the user's browser.  Other methods have included external applications running on the user's computer.  When they click a link, the file to be downloaded is added to a queue in a database.  The client application gets this data and will download it.  AudioGalaxy used to use this method.

Comment: Your question is not really a questions that's why you see some downvotes. Also it's not really a programming question and obviously you didn't do your homework and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple. Make them download an executable. They then need to execute it, and that executable than can take care to install a plugin into their browser that is able to write to disk and all that fun.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, PHP is not client side language so something like this is not possible to do it in.

Next, as you can see in comments on your question, due to security reasons such actions are not allowed by browsers.