# How to download .exe file from server at a predefined location using window.open method or xmlhttprequest onject?

Tags: javascript, gwt, xmlhttprequest, window.open

My problem is that i want to read an .exe file from server and save it to a predefined location. Currently I am using window.open method but it is opening a window and asking for the path. please tell me if know any such method and javascript or GWT is preferable.

Then I also tried to attach progress event with xmlhttprequest object which could tell me whether downloading is done or not but it is also not working fine and desired output is not coming.

Please help me with these two problems.

Hop to get a reply soon. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You can't.  Imagine the security nightmare if you could.  See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12863341/362536

Comment: Since this question has been marked as duplicated, you should open a new question with the xmlhttprequest part (it doesn't have an easy answer)

Comment: asked new question related to xmlhttprequest eventlistner and its link is   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851390/unable-to-attach-events-on-xmlhttprequest-object-or-window-object-used-to-downlo

Answer (score 0):

You can't save to a predefined location due to security implications.

Comment: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/…;.. I am trying to add progress event so as to know wheher download is done or not.. But browser is giving error that "Object does not support this property". Is there problem with the code or logic?

Comment: can i add window.onprogress event with window.open method using javascript? If yes, then please give a snippet of it. I want to do this, so that i cant track whethe the downloading is done or not?